# How to link a D library in a C program?

Tags: c, linux, linker, shared-libraries, d

I would like to call D functions that use the standard D library from a C program, how can I do it in linux?

Linking it statically does not seem to work (I get the dreaded "undefined reference to `_Dmodule_ref'" as well as 460 other errors, even when also linking a D main function), so I have tried to follow the instructions on https://dlang.org/dll-linux.html. Thanks to Ian Abbott for help with the instructions. I have distilled them down to the following working minimal hello world example:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/dlib
cd /tmp/dlib
cat ->hello_d.d <<EOF
import core.stdc.stdio;
extern(C) void hello_d() {
    printf( "hello from d\n");
}
EOF

cat ->main.c <<EOF
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    void *lh = dlopen( "/tmp/dlib/libhello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if( !lh) exit( 1);
    void (*hello_d)() = dlsym( lh, "hello_d");
    if( dlerror()) exit( 2);

    (*hello_d)();

    dlclose(lh);
}
EOF

dmd -c hello_d.d -fPIC
dmd -oflibhello.so hello_d.o -shared -defaultlib=libphobos2.so -L-rpath=/tmp/dlib
gcc -c main.c
gcc -rdynamic main.o -o main -ldl
./main
# Expect "hello from d"
cd -
```

However the instruction rely on core.stdc.stdio and the c printf function, but I would like to use the d library std.stdio and the d writeln function. If I do this I get a Segmentation fault when running the main program.
Please advice me how to link d functions (that make use of standard d libraries) into a c program.

Comment: The "/home/walter/tmp/libdll.so" was just an example shared library built earlier in the instructions you linked to.

Comment: https://dlang.org/dll-linux.html#dso9

Comment: Your example worked when I tried it with dmd v2.068.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I confirm the example works on Archlinux, DMD v2.070.0

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the segmentation fault and the linking errors is that required libraries are missing. This can be fixed by linking them in. Further more the d function must be "c compatible", so making it "nothrow" is a good idea. Below is code that solves the original question.

```
    mkdir -p /tmp/dlib
    cd /tmp/dlib
    cat ->hello_d.d <<EOF
    import std.stdio;
    extern(C) void hello_d() nothrow {
        try { writeln( "hello from d"); } catch( Throwable t) {}
    }
    EOF

    cat ->main.c <<EOF
    int main() {
        if( !rt_init()) { return 1; }
        hello_d();
        rt_term();
        return 0;
    }
    EOF

    gcc -c main.c
    dmd -c hello_d.d
    gcc -rdynamic main.o hello_d.o -o main -m64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Xlinker --export-dynamic -Xlinker -Bstatic -lphobos2 -Xlinker -Bdynamic -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl 
    ./main
    # Expect "hello from d"
    cd -
```

A way to identify the libraries to link in is to use the -v option in dmd:

```
dmd hello_d.d main.o -v | grep gcc
```